# Angular 5 App in Cake PHP template

Tags: angular, cakephp

I'm going to build an Angular 5 App with an existing application which is currently running on CakePHP(2.0),I want to develop using API calls but client insists to load Angular5 application in cake template and use some information from Cake session like current user information instead of pulling from server. Is there any way I can Angular 5 App in cake template as Angular caches HTML templates, I'd really appreciate any helping material if its possible.

Comment: anyone marking my question as negative please provide your opinion on it.

Comment: Are you planning on using cakePHP's templates (html)? Or is it just to provde some data

Comment: You can't pass informations from CakePHP into Angular application even if Ng app is served by CakePHP template. Only way to do this is print global javascript variables by CakePHP template engine then read them in Angular. Much better solution is make independent serwer side and client side and communicate by API calls. It is more elastic, more scalable, easier to develop.

Comment: @David client insists using Cake PHP's templates (ctp) so I want to know if it is possible with Angular 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all your DOMElement have to be manage by Angular himself. On your pure html part, you just need to add your boostraped component tag such as :

`<app-root></app-root>`

then, as explained by @karol you can provide any information to your application like this :

```
// Rest of your template
<script>
window.myAppNamespace = {
    post : <?= json_encode($myPostData) ?>  
};
</script>
// Rest of your template
```

Technically for both information explained above, you can use any render engine such as Cake PHP engine.

then on your Angular application, from anywhere (but prefer on service) you can do something like :

*i assume your structure is like this*

```
export interface PostModel {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    comments: Array<{
        author : string;
        content: string;
    }>;
}
@Injectable()
export PostService {
    private post: PostModel;

    constructor() {
        this.post = (window.myAppNamespace as any).post;
        // From here you can use your data provided by your CakePHP app.
    }
}
```

Comment: my pleasure, i am happy to help you

Comment: I''m having trouble with routing now, when I set base href to webroot/angular_files, router redirects me to webroot/angular_files, it appends base href to url I guess, any help/thoughts upon that?

Comment: Is another question related to another issue, you should ask it on new question, if you link this question here, i will try to answer